# Manila to Nagoya six day layover Nagoya to San Francisco

Tags: luggage, layovers, luggage-storage

I have two 23kg boxes from Manila to Nagoya.  Could I check my two 23kg boxes through directly to my next flight from Nagoya to San Francisco that will fly six days after my arrival in Nagoya?

Answer (score 2):

Even overnight checking luggage is extremely rare, multiple days is not possible. According  to the airport page, however, [Baggage Storage](https://www.centrair.jp/en/faq/baggage_storage.html) is available.

> If you want to store luggage for five or more days, including the initial day, you can use the short-term baggage storage counter.